# Execute command denied to user ''@'localhost' for routine error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, privileges, sql-grant

I have some problem during open my old website. My dataTable show:

```
DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.
```

After that, I tried to debug my script and found error in mysql:

```
Error occuered during query execution: 
(<small>SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ID,name,remark,avrusepmonth 
        , CONCAT('&lt;input type=''checkbox''id=''cb' , ID ,''' name=''check[]''                
        value=''',ID,''' &gt;','&lt;label class=''lbcb'' for=''cb', 
        ID,'''&gt;&lt;=update=&lt;/label&gt;') as checkb 
        ,monthavrage(ID,12) as latestavr , moq, leadtime 
        FROM test_media  WHERE nowuse=1 and monthavrage(ID,12)  &gt; 0  ORDER BY  name
        desc, ID
        LIMIT 0, 10</small>):
 execute command denied to user 'jeinqa'@'localhost' for routine 'TestMediaControl.monthavrage'
```

Then I tried to googling for `execute command denied to user 'jeinqa'@'localhost' for routine 'TestMediaControl.monthavrage'` and some sites said that I must do some `GRANT`:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE TestMediaControl.monthavrage TO 'jeinqa'@'localhost'
```

but I got:

```
#1370 - execute command denied to user 'jeinqa'@'localhost' for routine 'TestMediaControl.monthavrage'
```

could you tell me how should I do for solving this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It works.....
I try to grant this priviledge in `root`.

1. log in as `root`
2. `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE TestMediaControl.monthavrage TO 'jeinqa'@'localhost'`
3. `flush privileges;`

Answer (score 19):

Very late to the party also try a combination of.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE TestMediaControl.monthavrage TO 'jeinqa'@'%';
```

AND

```
flush privileges;
```

Also try replacing PROCEDURE with FUNCTION.

Answer (score 8):

I have encountered this in phpMyAdmin, a few hours ago, when executing a stored procedure with what I thought would be detected as a syntax error.

I was missing a comma between a field name, and a calculated field, and this gave me the same error message.

Comment: Ha ha, this is not a technical solution for problem but a solution to syntax error and I had a same problem that I could solved using this one... Great....! (I wish I could give 2 upvotes to this answer)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when trying to use the MIN function in my query.

```
Error Code: 1370. execute command denied to user 'a.user'@'%' for routine 'mysqlserver.MIN'
```

MySQL didn't like seeing a space before MIN and the opening (.

After reading the above and trying MIN(..) instead of MIN (..) my query worked.

Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem too - my error was quoting was with routine count - access denied.

The problem was I had "count (case when...)" and there cannot be a space between count and (. removing spaces fixed the error.

Comment: This is pretty weird as I already had the privileges. But this worked for me! None of the answers did, thanks

Comment: Yes, this was exactly my issue. This is an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered this yesterday, I expected a syntax error but this message was shown.

My mistake: I wrote "SELECT m.id, m.MAX(id_number) as id_number..." instead of "SELECT m.id, MAX(m.id_number) as id_number...".... the error is with the MAX. The error message wasn't too helpful.

Comment: This seems to be a follow up question. Maybe it would be better to post this as a comment, rather than a question. If you have a question please start a new one.

Comment: @Marcinek This seems to me like another situation where the mentioned error may confusingly occur, and how to fix it by fixing the SQL.