# Could not execute query in MySQL (issue with privileges)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc, privileges

I am trying to do this:

```
grant select on `mysql`.`proc` to `some_user`%`host`;
grant execute on procedure `database_name`.`get_some_data` to `some_user`@`host`;
flush privileges;
```

When my application calls, it throws the following error:

```
 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - execute command denied to user 'some_user'@'142.24.%.%' for routine 'database_name.get_some_data' at
 com.lsa.nameless.dao.AnalyticsDao.callStoredProcedure(AnalyticsDao.java:43)
 at com.lsa.nameless.service.AnalyticsService.findBrandPerformanceData(AnalyticsService.java:1672) 
 at com.lsa.nameless.action.AnalyticsAction.showPage(AnalyticsAction.java:240)
```

When I do execute `show grants for user@host`, I do see that I the user actually has privileges to execute the procedures and functions.

I have also tried granting privileges on procedures and functions separately. Still, not working.

Comment: Add your code and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @Jens - added the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Looks like the user you logged on with have no privileges to execute grant statements

Comment: @Jens - updated the summary, last time it worked by just doing a grant select on mysql.proc to the user@host.

Comment: The stacktrace contains the username `some_user` whilst your SQL uses `user`.

Comment: @still_learning - I had to change the user/host name. Security issues. some_user and user are the same.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434573