# Deleting a record from database inside of python gave an error

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I tried deleting a record inside of python for my database DB and it gave me error,

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1370 (42000): execute command denied to user 'user'@'%' for routine 'e7.get'
```

e7.get is the input from an entry box in tkinter and i tried the same command in mysql workbench,

```
DELETE FROM PATIENTS WHERE Patient_name=random_name
```

and it worked inside of mysql workbench, only problem is when i use the variable, and some privillage error? im using a online free hosting website db4free.net . I have tried grant privilage and it gives another error that `#1044 - Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'DB'`  Server does support remote access. Thanks in advance :)
EDIT : I TRIED PUTTING e7.get() in quotes and it dint give the error but it did nothing and the record still exists.

CODE:

```
def delete():
    con = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='user', password='*****', database='DB')
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM PATIENTS WHERE gender = 'e7.get()' ")
    c.execute('commit')
    con.close()
    e7.delete(0, END)
```

gives no error but does not delete the record.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database in python? Are you passing authentication credentials to the database? Can you post your python code?

I found another post that answers a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7370436/10151980

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql: execute command denied to user ''@'localhost' for routine error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434573/mysql-execute-command-denied-to-user-localhost-for-routine-error)

Comment: i have added the code in :)

Comment: actually that error was solved by using 'e7.get()' in quotes which i did not use before.... now the problem is that it does no good and record still exists

Comment: Can you try: c.execute(f"DELETE FROM PATIENTS WHERE gender = {e7.get()} ")

Comment: sorry it gives error ```mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Male' in 'where clause' ``` i think they took the value as a column :(

Comment: how about quotes around the brackets? '{e7.get()]'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213457/discussion-between-kickin-wing-and-cool-cloud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even python is susceptible to SQL injection so use parametrized queries and avoid the python/sql escaping complications:

```
 c.execute('DELETE FROM PATIENTS WHERE gender = %s', (e7.get()))
```

see [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html)

Comment: connection has a commit method too: [con.commit()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to insert the return value of e7.get() into your sql command.

in python you can use:

```
c.execute(f"DELETE FROM PATIENTS WHERE gender = '{e7.get()}' ")
```

or you can use:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM PATIENTS WHERE gender = '{}' ".format(e7.get())
```

either of those will insert the return value of `e7.get()` into your string