# How to remove some special character from database column in where condition to match another string?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a read only database. where i want to compare two string. But in the database some column value name has included some special character but i want to compare another string with this string without special character.

For example, In DB the column value name is `BMW 3-SERIES`. And i have another string `BMW3SERIES`. So, i want to remove `-` and `space` then compare two string in a where condition. Is both string equal or not ?

I am stuck how to remove special characters from `model_name` .

```
SELECT * FROM VENDOR WHERE model_name = "BMW3SERIES"
```

What should be the query?

Answer (score 2):

On MySQL 8+, you could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove what you deem as special characters, for example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM VENDOR
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(model_name, '[ -]+', '') = 'BMW3SERIES';
```

You may add whatever characters you wish to the above character class `[ -]+`.

Comment: I executed this query =>  

SELECT * FROM `tb_vehicle_models` WHERE brand_id = 1 and REGEXP_REPLACE(model_name, '[ -]+', '') = 'TSX' 

Got error : Error 1370: execute command denied to user

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?  If < 8, my answer won't work.

Comment: My version of MySQL is  8.0.28

Comment: Your version is fine, you may have some permissions issue going on.

Comment: Without REGEXP_REPLACE my query execute fine . For REGEXP_REPLACE is there need any specific permissions?

Comment: Not sure, it could actually still be a version issue.

Comment: @Md.AbuFarhad See [Mysql: execute command denied to user ''@'localhost' for routine error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434573)

Comment: Tyou probably need to swap the dash and space.

Comment: @RickJames No typo whatsoever.  Dash appearing anywhere _besides_ the final position in a character class might be interpreted as forming a range, which isn't what my intention is.  You should review regular expressions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Seems to be "besides _first or last_ position.  (Maybe we are both mistaken??)