# Concatenating two fields and replacing special/spaces characters

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I have sample data that looks like the following:

| fname | lname |
| --- | --- |
| x abc | jkn |
| test | test gth |
| yg-txs | gb@y |

Need to write simple query to

- remove all special character and spaces,
- concat fname and lname
- put it in fullname column, whereas values contained in this field must be without spaces and special characters.

Need optimized query because we have millions of data.

"*Expected Output*":

| fname | lname | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x abc | jkn | xabcjkn |
| test | test gth | testtestgth |
| yg-txs | gb@y | ygtxsgby |

I have tried below it didn't work:

- `REGEXP_REPLACE({column}, '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '')`
- `(REPLACE(CONCAT(fname,lname), '[$!&*_;:@#+\'=%^,<.>/?|~-]', '')`

Comment: fname and lname can contain spaces but when we concatinate both and display in fullname that time it shouldn't contain spaces, specialcharacters etc... @ just for example it might not be special character but except alphabets and number need to remove all other.

Comment: "it didn't work" - what happens instead? What else did you try to reoslve the problem?

Comment: Why your first option is not supposed to work? Looks like working correctly when excluding the space inside the non required characters.

Comment: `SELECT concat( REGEXP_REPLACE(fname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', ''), REGEXP_REPLACE(lname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '') ) as fullname;`

Comment: Or if you want a space between the first and last name `SELECT concat( REGEXP_REPLACE(@fname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', ''), ' ', REGEXP_REPLACE(@lname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '') ) as fullname;`

Comment: May be better to execute REGEXP_REPLACE once only, by swapping the order of the operations.

Comment: @lemon That would work if you dont want a space between firstname and lastname :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the space on the `REGEX` rest all looks good

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
(
    fname   VARCHAR(512),
    lname   VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO tableName (fname, lname) VALUES ('x abc', 'jkn');
INSERT INTO tableName (fname, lname) VALUES ('test', 'test gth');
INSERT INTO tableName (fname, lname) VALUES ('yg-txs', 'gb@y');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(fname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '')fname, 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(lname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '')lname, 
        CONCAT(REGEXP_REPLACE(fname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', ''),
               REGEXP_REPLACE(lname, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '')
        ) fullname 
FROM tableName;
```

| fname | lname | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x abc | jkn | xabcjkn |
| test | test gth | testtestgth |
| ygtxs | gby | ygtxsgby |

Comment: Get this error : Error Code: 1370. execute command denied to user 'xyz'@'%' for routine 'test.REGEXP_REPLACE', able to do all other SELECT but when I use REGEXP_REPLACE getting error

Comment: Looks like a permission issue on the `EXECUTE` command, instead of calling the execute. Are you able to use the `SELECT` and get the results as expected ?

Comment: I am using SELECT only still I get the denied error

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434573/mysql-execute-command-denied-to-user-localhost-for-routine-error

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed in the comments section, your issue is related to the space existing inside your regex. Additionally, employing the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) only once may give you a margin of efficiency improvement, if your requirement is not having a space between first and last name.

```
SELECT fname,
       lname,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(fname,lname), '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '') AS fullname
FROM tab
```

**Output**:

| fname | lname | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x abc | jkn | xabcjkn |
| test | test gth | testtestgth |
| yg-txs | gb@y | ygtxsgby |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hCEfqmxRbGQELVLauzzmBM/0).

Note: If you can't use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` command, you should ask for permissions to your provider. This is relevant as long as you're working on millions of data and require an optimized solution.